# Store the images picked from gallery android

Tags: android

I want to click the "btnchooserphoto" button to pick the images from gallery and
I can do it now, but I want to store these images and when I click "btnchooserphoto" button again I can add another images and the images I picked are still there. But now the ImageLoader will re-init everytime...  log is below

**W/ImageLoader(4503): Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. To re-init ImageLoader with new configuration call ImageLoader.destroy() at first.**

Can anybody know how to fix it? thanks!!!

These are my code...

**Album_Main**

```
public class Album_Main extends Activity {

private Button mbtn,mbtn_choosephoto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.album_setting);

        mbtn_choosephoto=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnchooserphoto);
        mbtn_choosephoto.setOnClickListener(mbtnchoosephotoonclick);
}


private View.OnClickListener mbtnchoosephotoonclick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent it = new Intent();
        it.setClass(Album_Main.this, Album_Setting.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
};


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**Album_Setting**

```
public class Album_Setting extends Activity {

GridView gridGallery;
Handler handler;
GalleryAdapter adapter;

ImageView imgSinglePick;
Button btnGalleryPick;
Button btnGalleryPickMul;
Button mbtngoback;

String action;
ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
ImageLoader imageLoader;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.album_setting_main);


    initImageLoader();
    init();

}

private void initImageLoader() {
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            this).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache(
            new WeakMemoryCache());

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);

}

private void init() {

    handler = new Handler();
    gridGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridGallery);
    gridGallery.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    adapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), imageLoader);
    adapter.setMultiplePick(false);
    gridGallery.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
    viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(1);

    mbtngoback=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btngoback);
    mbtngoback.setOnClickListener(mbtngobackonclick);


    btnGalleryPickMul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGalleryPickMul);
    btnGalleryPickMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(i, 200);
        }
    });

}

private View.OnClickListener mbtngobackonclick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
    }
};
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String[] all_path = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");

        ArrayList<CustomGallery> dataT = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();

        for (String string : all_path) {
            CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();
            item.sdcardPath = string;

            dataT.add(item);
        }

        storeimage(dataT);
    }
}
private void storeimage(ArrayList<CustomGallery> dataT){
    viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(0);
    adapter.addAll(dataT);
}
```

}

**CustomGalleryActivity**

```
public class CustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {

GridView gridGallery;
Handler handler;
GalleryAdapter adapter;

ImageView imgNoMedia;
Button btnGalleryOk;

String action;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    action = getIntent().getAction();
    if (action == null) {
        finish();
    }

        initImageLoader();
        init();



}

private void initImageLoader() {
    try {
        String CACHE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/.temp_tmp";
        new File(CACHE_DIR).mkdirs();

        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(getBaseContext(),
                CACHE_DIR);

        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).cacheOnDisc(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getBaseContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache());

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

private void init() {

    handler = new Handler();
    gridGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridGallery);
    gridGallery.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    adapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), imageLoader);
    PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader,
            true, true);
    gridGallery.setOnScrollListener(listener);

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK)) {

        findViewById(R.id.llBottomContainer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gridGallery.setOnItemClickListener(mItemMulClickListener);
        adapter.setMultiplePick(true);

    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Action.ACTION_PICK)) {

        findViewById(R.id.llBottomContainer).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        gridGallery.setOnItemClickListener(mItemSingleClickListener);
        adapter.setMultiplePick(false);

    }

    gridGallery.setAdapter(adapter);
    imgNoMedia = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgNoMedia);

    btnGalleryOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGalleryOk);
    btnGalleryOk.setOnClickListener(mOkClickListener);

    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.addAll(getGalleryPhotos());
                    checkImageStatus();
                }
            });
            Looper.loop();
        };

    }.start();

}

private void checkImageStatus() {
    if (adapter.isEmpty()) {
        imgNoMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        imgNoMedia.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

View.OnClickListener mOkClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayList<CustomGallery> selected = adapter.getSelected();

        String[] allPath = new String[selected.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < allPath.length; i++) {
            allPath[i] = selected.get(i).sdcardPath;
        }

        Intent data = new Intent().putExtra("all_path", allPath);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();

    }
};
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemMulClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        adapter.changeSelection(v, position);

    }
};

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemSingleClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        CustomGallery item = adapter.getItem(position);
        Intent data = new Intent().putExtra("single_path", item.sdcardPath);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
};

private ArrayList<CustomGallery> getGalleryPhotos() {
    ArrayList<CustomGallery> galleryList = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();

    try {
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                null, null, orderBy);

        if (imagecursor != null && imagecursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (imagecursor.moveToNext()) {
                CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();

                int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                item.sdcardPath = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);

                galleryList.add(item);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // show newest photo at beginning of the list
    Collections.reverse(galleryList);
    return galleryList;
}
```

}